# react .map() interpreted as a property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm newbie to react, I'm trying to get started with it. 
For that reason I'm trying to create an app like the tower of heroes in angular (which displays a list of heroes, and by clicking on one of them, you navigate to the detail page ).

 here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Route,
    Switch,
    HashRouter,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var prod = this.props.persons;
        return (
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        {prod.map(p => (
                            <li key={p.id} p={p}><Link key=                         {p.id} to='/detail'>{p.name}</Link>                                 </li>)
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                {
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component=                              {Test} />
                        <Route path='/detail' component=                              {Detail} />
                    </Switch>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class Detail extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p> {this.props.person.name} </p>
        )
    }
}
var PERSONS = [
    {id:'1', name: 'name1', age: '20' },
    {id:'2', name: 'name2', age: '21' },
    {id:'3', name: 'name3', age: '22' },
    {id:'4', name: 'name4', age: '23' },
    {id:'5', name: 'name5', age: '24' },
    {id:'6', name: 'name6', age: '25' }
];
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Test persons={PERSONS} />
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

in the browser I get that error : 
[image]

and also I remark that in the console there is other errors :
[image]

Comment: The error means `this.props.persons` is undefined, most likely you're not passing it down correctly.

Comment: Two culprits in this segment: `<li key={p.id} p={p}...`. (1) You're binding key to the `id` of each person object, which you haven't defined on any of the person objects in your `PERSONS` array. (2) `p` doesn't exist as a `property` of the native HTML element `li`.

Comment: @Nit, thank you for responding, but as you can see I passed the persons props, from the render ( <Test persons={PERSONS} />) to the Test component

Comment: <li key={p.id} p={p}><Link key=

Seems to be missing parts, what is this whole line? Is this the entire body of code, I don't see how the map fails (but I can see how it would fail to display anything due to some invalid component work there/variable selections).

Comment: @bazzells, 1) as you said the id element property doesn't exist, in fact I just forget to add. I made an update that include it, but the errors still exist.

Comment: @bazzells, 2) I think that the  `p` is the currently used element by the callback of the map() function

Comment: You're right on that, it is the current element passed to the callback. This `p` is on the _right side_ of the assignment here: `p={p}`. The second warning shown in the photo you posted is referring to the _left side_ of that assignment, which implies that `li` has a `prop` of `p`, but it doesn't. To silence this warning, you'll need to remove `p={p}`.

Comment: you were right, but I wonder how to passe the current person `p` to the detail view (as a props)

Comment: You can use a component instead of the standard `li`. Then you can pass the current `person` to that component.

Comment: One option would be: if you're using a flux implementation, you could have a `selectedDetail` in your `store`, update the `selectedDetail` on click of the `li`, then have the `detail` component refer to the `selectedDetail` in the `store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Test} />
```

This renders the component `Test` but does not pass the data as a prop.

One way to avoid this is to set a default prop for `Test` to an empty array:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
      persons: []
    };

    render() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you were right, I removed the ` <Route exact path='/' component={Test} />`, and the 1st error disappears, but the sconde still exist

Comment: Also if I use your solution I'm getting some errors because `this.props.persons.map(p => ..;` is still unkown, and if I use persons directly I will not be able to show data passed by the props

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines are problematic:

```
{prod.map(p => (
    <li key={p.id} p={p}>
        <Link key={p.id} to='/detail'>{p.name}</Link>
    </li>
))}
```

By definition the `li`-tag does not have a property called `p`.
Additionally, only the parent element, here the `li`-tag, only needs a key.

So the lines should look like this:

```
{prod.map(p => (
    <li key={p.id}>
        <Link to='/detail'>{p.name}</Link>
    </li>
))}
```

I hope this resolves your issues.